# Compare content of two files

Tags: python

I am comaring 2 files with same names in 2 directories as follows: This is my pseudocode and I have also included the code I wrote for this program.

```
dir1 = "/home/1"
dir2 = "/home/2"

loop through all the files in dir1 and dir2
if the name of file in dir1 is same as the name then:
    for those particular files:
        read all the lines in file1 in dir1 and file2 in dir2
        #the file1.txt dir1 has below data( just an example my files data are different):
        20 30 40
        2 7 8
        #file1.txt in dir2 has below data:
        31 41 51
        11 14 14            
        #I want to now compare these files in the following way:
        #compare each line in file1.txt in dir with each line of 
        file1.txt in dir2
        (i.e first line of file1.txt in dir1 with 1st, 2nd, 3rd..last 
        line of file1.txt in dir2....
         second line with 1st,2nd,3rd...last line and so on)
        If the difference of all the corresponding elements(i.e 20- 
        31<=10 and 30-41<=10 and 40-51<=10 then 
        print the 1st line of file1.txt of dir1)
        do the same thing for each line of each files print out the 
        result.
```

This is my code:

```
dir1 = "/home/one"


dir2 = "/home/two"

for file in os.listdir(dir1):
file2 = os.path.join(dir2, file)
if os.path.exists(file2):
    file1 = os.path.join(dir1, file)
    print(file)
    with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
        # how to do the comparison?
        # how to compare first four element of line 1 of f1 with all the first four 
          #element of each line of f2 ?**
        same = True
        while True:
            line1 = f1.readline().split()[:4]
            print(line1)
            line2 = f2.readline().split()[:4]
            print(line2)
            # one way to compare but is not very logical and thorough
            if all(float(el1)-float(el2) < 11 for el1, el2 in zip(line2, line1)): 
                print(el1,el2)              
                same = True
            if len(line1) == 0:
                break
        if same:
            print(line1)
            #print(el1, el2) 
            #print(line2)
        else:
            print("files are different")
```

I think I am missing something, because it doesn't print all the similar lines as it should.

If input file are as follows:

file1.txt in dir1:

```
10 20 30
100 200 300
1000 2000 3000
```

file1.txt in dir2:

```
15 30 40
120 215 315
27 25 35
```

Expected output:

```
10 20 30
```

(as 1st line of file1.txt in dir1 satisfies the condition with only the first line of file1.txt in dir2 where 10-15<=10 and 20-30<=10 and 30-40=10<=10 ( consider all modulus)

Comment: I just copy and pasted it to match the format, so it could be the error while pasting

Comment: I edited the code, I hope this is right

Comment: Can you show some example input and expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected output

Comment: Have you checked if the values of `el1` and `el2` are what you expect?

Comment: how can I check that

Comment: e.g. `for el1, el2 in zip(line1, line2): print(el1, el2)`.

Comment: I can;t print them out for some reason it says IndentationError:unindent does not match any outer indentation level, but I dont think there is any indention error. I simply put the print statement as shown in my edited code above

Comment: The code after the `with` statement should be indented.

Comment: It was copy paste error, I have corrected the question, I am still getting the same error:
File "compare.py", line 47
    same = True
              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is important in python

Comment: I fixed the indentation, but it says: NameError: name 'el1' is not defined, where do I have to define el1 and el2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fairly tricky as there is a number of requirements. If I understand correctly, they are:

- get a list of files in first directory
- for each file find file with same name in second directory
- get corresponding line in paired files
- compare corresponding value in each line
- if all values in a line match criteria print line in first file

It can be easier to create such a script if you break the problem down into smaller problems and test each piece. Python allows you to do this with functions for each piece.

As an example you could break your problem down as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def get_matching_file(known_file, search_dir):
    f2_file = search_dir.joinpath(known_file.name)
    if f2_file.exists():
        return f2_file
    raise FileNotFoundError


def get_lines(file_loc):
    result = []
    lines = file_loc.read_text().splitlines()
    for row in lines:
        row_as = []
        for num in row.split():
            row_as.append(int(num))
        result.append(row_as)
    return result


def compare_content(f1_rows, f2_rows):
    result = []
    for row1 in f1_rows:
        for row2 in f2_rows:
            row_result = []
            for v1, v2 in zip(row1, row2):
                # print(f'{v2} - {v1} = {v2 - v1}')
                row_result.append(abs(v2 - v1) <= 10)
            if all(row_result):
                result.append(row1)
    return result


def print_result(result):
    for line in result:
        print(' '.join(str(int(num)) for num in line))


def main(dir1, dir2):
    for file_one in dir1.glob('*.txt'):
        file_two = get_matching_file(file_one, dir2)
        f1_content = get_lines(file_one)
        f2_content = get_lines(file_two)
        result = compare_content(f1_content, f2_content)
        print_result(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(dir1=Path(r'/Temp/text_compare/one'),
         dir2=Path(r'/Temp/text_compare/two'))
```

The above gave me the output you were looking for of:

```
10 20 30
```

Structuring the code this way then allows you to test small parts of your script at a time. For example if I wanted to just test the `compare_content` function I could change the code at the bottom to read:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_result = compare_content(f1_rows=[[10, 20, 30]],
                                  f2_rows=[[15, 30, 40]])
    print('Test 1:', test_result)
    test_result = compare_content(f1_rows=[[100, 200, 300]],
                                  f2_rows=[[120, 215, 315]])
    print('Test 2:', test_result)
```

which would give the output:

```
Test 1: [[10, 20, 30]]
Test 2: []
```

Or test reading values from file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_result = get_lines(Path(r'/Temp/text_compare/one/log.txt'))
    print(test_result)
```

Gave the output of:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300], [1000, 2000, 3000]]
```

This also allows you to optimize just parts of your script. For example, you might want to use Python's `csv` module to simplify the reading of the files. This would require the change of just one function. For example:

```py
def get_lines(file_loc):
    with file_loc.open() as ssv:
        space_reader = csv.reader(ssv,
                                  delimiter=' ',
                                  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        return list(space_reader)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a thorough explanation. Currently it only compares corresponding lines( i.e first row of first file with first row of second file), but I want to compare first row of first file with all the rows of second file, second row of first file with all the rows of second file and so on. So, basically not only corresponding lines but all the lines(rows).

Comment: For instance: file1: 1203 215 315,
2733 253 36,
1500 3000 400,
file2: 1500 3000 400,
1203 215 315,
2733 253 35
Then the output should be  :1203 215 315,
2733 253 36,
1500 3000 400, .Because when we compare first line of first file i.e(1203 215 315) with first, second and third line of files 2 one by one(i.e 1500 3000 400,
1203 215 315,
2733 253 35)
Then first line of first file and second line of second file matched the condition (r1-r2<=10). Hence the output should include 1203 215 315. But currently if we test it, it only checks the corresponding line.

Comment: Updated `compare_content` function in the answer to reflect the data you have given in the above comment.